# Mod rewrite causing internal server error, error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

So, i learned about mod_rewrite and decided to use it with my site, my old url was like this

```
https://xenonmc.tk/?paramOne=register
```

and heres the output i was supposed to get with mod_rewirte

```
https://xenonmc.tk/register
```

heres is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1 [L]
```

I think ik the problem but i dont under stand how to fix it, even after viewing other articals on stackoverflow on this,

all i understood from thos is that [L] is causing my htaccess to loop again from the top causing the error.

[image]

Thanks for any support.

Comment: I suggest opening a different question for your edited part. It is not fair to change your requirements after getting a working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have an infinite loop getting created over there, we need to put a condition to avoid that(I am checking if query string is NULL then only run the rule by that no infinite loop), try:

Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before checking your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1 [L]
```

Comment: also one more question, i just updated my question with my actual file. , i used your method and the first get var worked, but when i add more, it say error 404 untill i fill all the url params, what shoudl i do

Comment: @Xfaon, to be honest without seeing htaccess file its very difficult, you have one problem solved now and you are good to go for second one :) on SO its encouraged to have 1 question at a post, you could share your htaccess in new question and I could take a look to it then, cheers.